# array to nested array conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my backend service send me list of node as an array. but I need is, each next node is value of its previous node(SEE EXAMPLE). I want whole list as nested object in singe object.

WHAT I HAVE:

```
[
        {
            "nodeId": 1,

        },
        {
            "nodeId": 3,

        },
        {
            "nodeId": 16,

        }
    ]
```

WHAT I NEED:

```
[
{
  "nodeId": 1,

  "staticChild": [
    {
      "nodeId": 3,

      "staticChild": [
        {
          "nodeId": 16,

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: could you have more elements with different nestings?

Comment: Is the only determinant of the child relationship, the position of the object in the original array? In other words, if you add a fourth element in the array, would it be a child of the third element?

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array from the right side and build a new object with a `staticChild` property.

```js
var array = [{ nodeId: 1 }, { nodeId: 3 }, { nodeId: 16 }],
    result = array.reduceRight((a, b) => ({ ...b, staticChild: [a] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input / output you provided, you can use a recursive funtion like :

```js
const data = [{
    nodeId: 1
  },
  {
    nodeId: 3
  },
  {
    nodeId: 16
  }
];

const transform = data => {
  const [node, ...rest] = data;
  if (rest.length > 0) {
    return {
      ...node,
      staticChild: [transform(rest)]
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...node,
      hasChildren: false
    };
  }
};

const result = transform(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first reverse the array and the make an iteration over the revered array using [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to make your desire format.

```js
let data = [{"nodeId": 1},{"nodeId": 3},{"nodeId": 16}]

data = data.reverse().reduce((old, cur) => {
    if (!old.length) {
        old = [cur]
    } else {
        cur['staticChild'] = old
        old = [cur]
    }
    return old
}, [])

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Using the `reduceRight()` will allow you to skip the `reverse()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduceRight()` array method to perform the transformation.

```js
const data = [{
    "nodeId": 1,

  },
  {
    "nodeId": 3,

  },
  {
    "nodeId": 16,

  }
]

const nested = data.reduceRight((acc, item) => {
  return [ { ...item, staticChild: acc } ]
}, []);

console.log(nested);
```

Or more succinctly:

```js
const nested = data.reduceRight((acc, item) => [ { ...item, staticChild: acc } ],[]);
```